# How to make a div follow the cursor?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a tooltip for a navigation bar, the code is below.
I'd like to have the div follow the mouse cursor, which function is needed to achieve this?

```
$('div#navigation a').hover(function() {
    $('div#tooltip').fadeIn(500)
}, function() {
    $('div#tooltip').fadeOut(100)
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the [numerous jQuery tooltip libraries](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip) available?

Comment: The mouse cursor isn't a DOM element so you can't append nodes to it. Your question doesn't make sense, can you be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Jared, I am trying to learn jQuery. :D Though, I will have a look at the libraries, perhaps I can learn from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `mousemove` get the mouse `event` coordinates `pageX` and `pageY`

```js
var $tooltip = $("#tooltip");

$(document).on("mousemove", function(evt) {
  $tooltip.css({left: evt.pageX, top: evt.pageY});
});
```

```css
#tooltip{position:absolute;background:red;width:20px;height:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

### Tooltip on hover using jQuery

Here's a basic plugin example

```js
(function($) {

  var moveTooltip = false,
      $tooltip = $("<div/>", {
        appendTo: "body",
        id: "tooltip",
        css: {
          position:"absolute",
          display:"none",
          zIndex:99999,
          maxWidth:160,
          padding:10,
          background:"#eee"
        }
      });

  $(document).mousemove(function(ev) {
    if(!moveTooltip) return;
    $tooltip.css({top: ev.pageY+15, left: ev.pageX+15});
  });

  $.fn.tooltip = function() {  
    return this.each(function(){
      $(this).hover(function() {
        moveTooltip = true;
        $tooltip.html($(this).data('tooltip')).fadeTo(300, 1);        
      },function(){
        moveTooltip = false;
        $tooltip.hide();
      });
    });
  };

}(jQuery));


$("nav a").tooltip();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="This is my title 1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="This is my title 2 ">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-tooltip="<b>This</b> is my title 3.<br>A new line">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>   
</nav>
```

Note: you might want to further improve on that code restricting the position of the tooltip to the viewport boundaries, you got the idea.

Comment: Please provide a complete answer within your answer and refrain from posting just links to another (external) site. `:)`

Comment: @Jared , thanks, I know that. I'm right away finished with an example appropriate for the OP

Comment: No worries, that's not obvious unless there's a note left in the answer stating more to come.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get details of the mouse's location when the `hover()` event is fired. Once you know those details, you can position the tooltip accordingly.

Use the following CSS code to allow the positioning of the element:

```css
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Now that you have done this, modify your jQuery code to position the tooltip wherever the mouse is, and then fade it out when they mouseout of the navigation `div`:

```js
$('div#navigation a').hover(function(e) {
        var yPos = e.pageY;
        var xPos = e.pageX;
        $('div#tooltip').css({ top: yPos, left: xPos }).fadeIn(500)
    },
    function() {
        $('div#tooltip').fadeOut(100)
});
```

I've thrown together a quick jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aNRJW/